# python ide vs cmd line detection?

Tags: python

When programming in the two IDEs i used, bad things happen when i use raw_input. However on the command line it works EXACTLY how i expect it to. Typically this app is ran in cmd line but i like to edit and debug it in an IDE. Is there a way to detect if i executed the app in an IDE or not?

Comment: I don't get the question.  Are you unsure where you're running?  Or can you not test on the command line?  I don't get the use case at all.  Could you clarify what you're trying to do with an example or something?  And could you provide the code which doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise (and you have been previously advised on this) to use a good IDE, and a good debugger instead of hacking around your code to fix something that shouldn't be broken in the first place.

I deserve to be down-voted for not answering the question, but please consider this advice for your future sanity.

I would personally recommend [Winpdb debugger](http://winpdb.org/) and [PIDA IDE](http://pida.co.uk)

Answer (score 5):

```
if sys.stdin.isatty():
   # command line (not a pipe, no stdin redirection)
else:
   # something else, could be IDE
```